# No tengo vectores en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Antes me aparecían muchos iconos para poder crear drawables y ya no, como los recupero]

Antes me aparecían muchos iconos para poder crear drawables y ya no, como los recupero, yo los uso para hacer pruebas y ver como quedaría un icono antes de usar el original.

Comment: Cuál es tu versión de android studio? Probaste actualizar?

Comment: Gracias Crack tenía la 4.1, pero según investigue tenía ese bug, actualice y listo , gracias.

Comment: @Osdward suena excelente, podrías poner eso mismo como respuesta y aceptarla en cuanto puedas? Ayudaría mucho a la comunidad